PredicateBuilder Not Working in Loop, But Working Manually
I am trying to use LinqKit's PredicateBuilder to create some nested logic to compare against SQL, and this works fine when I manually specify the conditions, but when I place the code in a loop I get an ArgumentOutOfRangeException later on when I try to query based on the predicate I built. Here is my code:
var outerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
var innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
    for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
    {
        innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(y => y.Field<string>(sqlNames[i]) == filters[i][j]);
    }
    outerPredicate = outerPredicate.And(innerPredicate);
}

This code always produces the same ArgumentOutOfRangeException, even if I set each loop to run only once, but this code runs perfectly:
var outerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
var innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(y => y.Field<string>(sqlNames[3]) == filters[3][0]);
innerPredicate = outerPredicate.And(innerPredicate);
innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(y => y.Field<string>(sqlNames[2]) == filters[2][0]);
outerPredicate = outerPredicate.And(innerPredicate);
innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(y => y.Field<string>(sqlNames[1]) == filters[1][0]);
outerPredicate = outerPredicate.And(innerPredicate);
innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(y => y.Field<string>(sqlNames[0]) == filters[0][0]);
outerPredicate = outerPredicate.And(innerPredicate);

As far as I can tell, these two pieces of code are functionally identical. I would greatly appreciate anyone who can solve this mystery for me.

@RuneAndersen How would I break it down any more than this? I wasn't able to see the value of outerPredicate in my debugger, but it seems like I'm assembling it in the exact same way with both methods. Just for whatever reason, it doesn't like it when I do it in a loop.

It looks like you get one more row set in the loop at i=0  so you loose the reference. So don't do New<> for i==0

@RuneAndersen How is that? The loop goes from i=0 to i=3 and so does the manual method. I've set breakpoints and gone through the loop on each iteration and it definitely runs 4 times.

its the first innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New(); that overwrites every time

@RuneAndersen Yes I know, as does innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>(); overwrite it in the second method, only after outerPredicate = outerPredicate.And(innerPredicate); is run in both cases.

I am not an expert, but the examples I've looked at seed the predicate with PredicateBuilder.True<DataRow>() for AND chains and  PredicateBuilder.False<DataRow>() for OR chains, instead of PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>(). Not sure if that may be the problem. Other than that, I looked at the two versions of your code and they seem equivalent except for the index order (0..3 vs 3..0) and an extra (discarded) initialization - both of which seem to be don't care cases.

@TN Yes you are right - I didn't look close enough.

I think the problem is that the unroll has constants and the loop has variables where the expressions inside Or are lazy evaluated. A fix to try could be adding  var ii=i; and var jj=j; inside the loop and use them instead.

(My earlier True/False initializer comments was likely a dead end referencing obsolete usage.) I think @RuneAndersen has nailed it. After the last loop iterations, the values of i and j are likely left with values of 4 and 1, which cause the ArgumentOutOfRangeException when the predicates are lazy-evaluated. (There may actually be four separate instances of j hanging around, each with value = 1, due to closure bindings.)

This should do it:
   var outerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
    var innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        innerPredicate = PredicateBuilder.New<DataRow>();
        for (int j = 0; j < 1; j++)
        {
            var ii=i;var jj=j;
            innerPredicate = innerPredicate.Or(y => y.Field<string>(sqlNames[ii]) == filters[ii][jj]);
        }
        outerPredicate = outerPredicate.And(innerPredicate);
    }

see: Captured variable in a loop in C#

Wow, I never would have thought of this, what a weird quirk. The answer in that link says that this is fixed as of C# 5, but I'm using .NET 6.0 and this issue seems to still be present, or is that only for foreach?

See this answer.

@GertArnold Thank you! Very frustrating that this unsafe behaviour was fixed in foreach but not in for, now I know at least.

You could also use foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 4)) (and similar for j).  Why? Because foreach defines and initializes a fresh local variable for each iteration "with a scope that extends over the embedded statement" (C# language spec). In contrast, for loop variables are initialized once and modified (typically incremented) by the for_iterator after each loop iteration. This necessitates a wider more persistent scope: "The scope of a local variable declared by a for_initializer is the for_initializer, for_condition, for_iterator, and embedded_statement."

@TN Yeah I understand that the behaviour of foreach is different and comparatively safer than for, but it still seems like very unintuitive and really just buggy functionality that this kind of stuff can happen with for, especially when it seems very inconsistent as to when it's actually an issue or not. All this really means is that in practice I will probably never use for loops in C# again, and I'll just use foreach to replicate the same functionality.

"Fixing" the for statement to have separate copies of the iteration variable(s) for each loop execution would require some really weird semantics rewriting. A typical for_iterator i++ might need to be reimagined as something like var i_next = i; i_next++. Statements having multiple variables defined in the for_initializer and multiple arbrary expressions in the for_iterator would further complicate things. The scope of each variable instance is also complicated as preceding for_initializer or for_iterator, for_condition, embedded statement, and following for_iterator.

...The overlapping scope of the same-named (but different) variable(s) would (I expect) require further trickery in the IL representation and in the debugger. At the same time, I believe the resulting semantics might be even less intuitive for the programmer to understand.  So, I think leaving for variable scope as-is was probably the right decision by the language designers. We just need to accept the behavior as part of the language, which might be one of those "gotcha" behaviors you encounter once, learn from, and avoid in the future. (attn: @BobSmith)

@TN I'm just not sure I can see any reason why it would make sense to use for when this behaviour exists. It just seems like a less safe version of foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(x, y)), which is how for operates in other languages and how you would intuitively think it operates in C#.

I mean what's the point of using a for loop if you can't use the iterator variable within the loop, like as an index as I was trying to do? More than 90% of the time if I am writing a for loop, I am reading from the iterator variable in some way. Unless the loop is incredibly simple, if you're not accessing the iterator variable then it almost always makes more sense to use a foreach or while instead.

@BobSmith - It is only a "gotcha" if: (1) You are using for instead of foreach, (2) The iteration variable is directly used in a lambda function (or similar closure construct), and (3) That lambda function is persisted and has a deferred execution that occurs after that loop iteration. If neither of the latter two conditions apply, it is perfectly safe to use a for loop.
